# change default theme admin of croogo 2.0 (cakephp)?

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I try to change the default admin theme for croogo 2.0 ??.. I did all the configuration

existing...but don't work.

thank you to help me

my settings.json

```
            {
                "Site": {
                    "acl_plugin": "Acl",
                    "admin_theme": "Ace",
                    "asset_timestamp": "force",
                    "email": "you@your-site.com",
                    "feed_url": "",
                    "home_url": "",
                    "ipWhitelist": "127.0.0.1",
                    "locale": "eng",
                    "status": 1,
                    "tagline": "A CakePHP powered Content Management System.",
                    "theme": "Mytheme",
                    "timezone": 0,
                    "title": "MyTitle"
                },
                "Croogo": {
                    "Api": {
                        "path": "api"
                    },
                    "dashboardUrl": {
                        "admin":true,
                        "plugin": "extensions",
                        "controller": "extensions_dashboard",
                        "action": "index"
                    },
                    "installed": 1,
                    "version": "2.0.0"
                },
                "Hook": {
                    "bootstraps": "Settings,Comments,Contacts,Nodes,Meta,Menus,Users,Blocks,Taxonomy,FileManager,Wysiwyg,Ckeditor"
                },
                "Access Control": {
                    "autoLoginDuration": "+1 week",
                    "models": "",
                    "multiRole": 0,
                    "rowLevel": 0
                },
                "Comment": {
                    "date_time_format": "M d, Y",
                    "email_notification": 1,
                    "feed_limit": 10,
                    "level": 1
                },
                "Meta": {
                    "description": "Croogo - A CakePHP powered Content Management System",
                    "generator": "Croogo - Content Management System",
                    "keywords": "croogo, Croogo",
                    "robots": "index, follow"
                },
                "Reading": {
                    "date_time_format": "D, M d Y H:i:s",
                    "nodes_per_page": 5
                },
                "Service": {
                    "akismet_key": "your-key",
                    "akismet_url": "http://your-blog.com",
                    "recaptcha_private_key": "your-private-key",
                    "recaptcha_public_key": "your-public-key"
                },
                "Writing": {
                    "wysiwyg": 1
                }
            }
```

and I put my theme admin in /public_html/demo/View/Themed/Ace